# Search a word in rich edit control of devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to search a word in rich edit control. I will write a word in a text box and then click on a button named search button, and then the searched word will be highlighted in the rich edit control.

How can I solve this problem?

In rich text box we use `RichTextBox.TextLength`, but rich edit control doesn't support this.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //Search button
{
    int index = 0;
    while(index <= richEditControl1.Text.LastIndexOf(textBox1.Text))
    {
        richEditControl1.Find(textBox1.Text, index, richEditControl1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        richEditControl1.SelectionBackColor = Color.IndianRed;
        index = richEditControl1.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text, index) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check the fuzzy search? The output is similar to your request. There are few demo's if you have installed devexpress demo application.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [StartSearch](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.SubDocument.StartSearch.overloads) method. Something like this.

```
private void SearchRTF(string mytext) {
  var result = myRichEditControl.Document.StartSearch(mytext);
  if (result.FindNext()) {
    var section = myRichEditControl.Document.BeginUpdateCharacters(result.CurrentResult);
    section.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    section.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    myRichEditControl.Document.EndUpdateCharacters(section);
  }
}
```